# Handle files into sub-folders having the same parent in batch

Tags: batch-file, path

I run mybat.bat whose path is D:\path\to\my\data.

the "data" folder, that is my current directory, contains two folders namely "data1" and "data2". 
data1 contains file1.txt and data2 also contains file1 with another extension file name (file1.out)

I am at the current directory data where
 mybat.bat is being run.

I would pass the "file1.txt" and "file1.out" to a "tamo.bat", knowing that "tamo.bat" is the same directory as "mybat.bat" (the "data" directory) .

Here's I write, but it doesn't work!

```
  SET mypath=%~dp0
  set var=file1
  set getTXTBySubPath=%mypath%data1\%var%.txt
  echo -----getTXTBySubPath-----

  set getOUTBySubPath=%mypath%data2\%var%.out
  Call tamo.bat %getTXTBySubPath% %getOUTBySubPath%
```

Please how could I achieve that ? 
Thanks!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Is there an error message?  Does tamo.bat not get the values you expect?  (What values does it get?)  And please edit your question to fix the `var1`/`%var%` typo in your code if that is not what your real code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with some more double quotes:

```
SET "mypath=%~dp0"

set "var=file1"
set "getTXTBySubPath=%mypath%data1\%var%.txt"
echo -----getTXTBySubPath-----

set "getOUTBySubPath=%mypath%data2\%var%.out"
Call tamo.bat "%getTXTBySubPath%" "%getOUTBySubPath%"
```

Comment: Let me add that 'tamo.bat' calls a vbs code namely code.vbs where each parameter of code.vbs is a file, the first one is "file1.txt" and the second one is "file1.out" which is coming from mybat.bat

set first="%1"
set second="%2"
echo %first%
echo %second%

cscript code.vbs /x:%first% /y:%second%
I think that the parameters of code.vbs causes error, I don't know why and how to fix it.
Thank you your help

Comment: Try this `set "first=%~1"`   `set "second=%~2"`

Comment: the same error as before.                                           I don't know if it is important but code.vbs in turns get the first parameter like that
dim paramvbs: paramvbs=Wscript.Arguments.Named("x")
which is used for running a shell:
shell.run "another.bat """ & paramvbs & """ ""file.out"""

Does not code.vbs which causes error while calling 'another.bat'?, I don't know why and how to fix it.
Thank you your help.

Comment: I try a test with real values on calling code.vbs from tamo.bat like this

cscript code.vbs /x:"data1\my file 1.txt" /y:"data2\my file 1.out"

I notice that paramvbs: paramvbs=Wscript.Arguments.Named("x")
which is used for running a shell:
shell.run "another.bat """ & paramvbs & """ ""file.out"""
causes problem,therefore shell does not run....